# Destroying JSON Web Tokens

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, token

This is something,that really confuses. me. Let us suppose you have a REST API where you want the user to logout. After login out,the jwt(json web token) should be destroyed,so the user can not have access to the server's resources(ie menu,dishes etc).

In my case the user can logout,but he/she can still perform all the requests(get dishes,post and delete),until the token is valid. Here is my code.

**verify.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../config.js');

exports.getToken = function (user) {
      return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
          expiresIn: 3600
      });
};

exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
           if (err) {
               var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
               err.status = 401;
               return next(err);
           } else {
               // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
               req.decoded = decoded;
               next();
           }
        });
     } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
     }
};
```

I am invalidating the token after a period of 1 hour.

And **users.js** where I set all the routes with their tasks. ie *localhost:3000/users/login*,*localhost:3000/users/register* and *localhost:3000/users/logout*. So.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Verify    = require('./verify');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }),
    req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
           return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
             return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json(
            err: info
          });
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
             err: 'Could not log in user'
          });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
      res.status(200).json({
         status: 'Login successful!',
         success: true,
         token: token
      });
   });
 })(req,res,next);
});

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.status(200).json({
       status: 'Bye!'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It seems that the logout method *req.logout*,doesn't work:(. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot log out a user that has a valid token if all the data is on the client side. You would need to store some state on the server to distinguish between users that you explicitly logged out and those that you didn't and check this state every time. If all of the data is entirely in the JWT token then you can't do anything to make it invalid (other than changing your secret that would invalidate all of the tokens, not just this one).

You actually discovered the main disadvantage of using authentication based entirely on the data that is included in the token itself. Those tokens cannot be invalidated. Once they're out then must be assumed to be active. You could only ask the client to forget it, but the client cannot be trusted to do that.

In theory you might have a fast data store like Redis where you keep all of the valid tokens and remove tokens from there to force logout, and check this storage on every request to know who is still logged in and who is not, but if you do that then you might store the session data in Redis in the first place and give only some random keys to that data store to the clients.

Answer (score 2):

JWT is designed to be stateless. This means that all the information needed is contained in the token itself.

As the token has already been created, logout will have no effect on the validity of this.

This leaves you needing to keep a list of 'invalidated' tokens, which means you have once more introduced state.

If you are only concerned about subsequent users on the same machine, you could delete the token on logout, thus preserving the statelessness, but this will not protect against cases where the token has been captured.

Comment: So how can you remove the token? Is there any funtion for it?

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Imagine your app has 30 thousand logged in users. It is impossible to keep track all those tokens.lol.

Comment: @Theo re removing the token- this will depend on how its being stored, as cookie or in localstorage. re 30,000 users; a) you would only need to keep track of those who have logged out, potentially a much smaller number,  b) if you *are* worried about the token being captured, reducing security to reduce the amount of resources used is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I store all user's info in mongodb. ie. {
        "_id" : ObjectId("id goes here"),
        "salt" : "salt goes here",
        "hash" : "hash key goes here",
        "username" : "theodosios86",
        "admin" : true,
        "__v" : 0I
}. However from that I can't see when the user has logged out. ie I want a timestamp specifying the time of login out.

Comment: @Theo the token must be stored somewhere client side, and being sent with every request.

Comment: I have that in the client side after login in. The server gives me back a response. {"status":"Login successful!","success":true,"token":"token goes here"}. And as you mentioned I use that in every subsequent request(get,post,del,put). You mentioned that I should keep track only those who have logged out...This is the confusing part for me.

Comment: If I set for example the token to last one day,the user would have to login again when the token in expired.

Comment: or I can have the token valid for year and don't put a logout funtion:). How many people do logout anyway?